# Substitute Anchor code with Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, anchor

Yes, I want to replace a simple anchor link with a javascript array code. We're doing it the long (and possibly complicated) way over here. I figured it would be a simple scrollTo property but I still cant get the page to scroll or jump anywhere else on the page.
Can someone tell me if I'm doing something horribly wrong?

Here is the javascript.

```
$(function(){
    //Search index for Cards
    var gameA = new Array('normal','ex','promo','counterfeit');

    $('#go').click(function(e){
        var term = $('#term').val();
        var searchIndex = gameA.indexOf(term);
        console.log(term);
        console.log(searchIndex);
        if (searchIndex > -1){
            console.log("hi");
            window.scrollTo(0,"#sec"+searchIndex);
        } 
    });
});
```

And here is my source code.

```
<h2 id="top">Select a Term</h2>
<p>List: Normal, Ex, Promo, Counterfeit</p>
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
<label for"term">Enter a term from the list above.</label><br>
<input type="text" id="term" name="term">
<button id="go">Go</button>
</form>
</div>
<br><br>
<img src="images/fancycards.jpg" width="1191" height="670" alt="fancy cards"><br>

<h2 id="sec0">Normal Cards</h2>
<p><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></p>
<img src="images/cards.jpg" width="1131" height="707" alt="cards"><br>

<h2 id="sec1">Ex Cards</h2>
<p></p>
<img src="images/excards.jpg" width="1000" height="653" alt="ex cards"><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo) takes coordinates for both arguments, rather than an element's ID.

Try the following in place of your current `scrollTo` command:

```
window.scrollTo(0, $("#sec"+searchIndex).offset().top)
```

Here's a JSFiddle example that includes this change. The images obviously won't show up, but it does scroll properly: http://jsfiddle.net/1mpqm1te/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a number to the scrollTo() function, not a string. This would be the Y offset of the element you want to scroll to. Here is an updated version! If we give the card sections semantically sensical ID values ('normal-cards', 'ex-cards', etc), we can easily make this happen!

http://jsfiddle.net/yLvhh53a/

```js
$(function () {
    //Search index for Cards
    var gameA = new Array('normal', 'ex', 'promo', 'counterfeit');

    $('#go').click(function (e) {
        var term = $('#term').val();
        console.log(term);
        var item = $('#' + term + '-cards');
        console.log(item);
        
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: item.offset().top
        }, 1000);


    });

});
```

```html
<h2 id="top">Select a Term</h2>

<p>List: Normal, Ex, Promo, Counterfeit</p>
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <label for "term">Enter a term from the list above.</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="term" name="term">
    <button id="go">Go</button>
</form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<img src="images/fancycards.jpg" width="1191" height="670" alt="fancy cards">
<br>

<h2 id="normal-cards">Normal Cards</h2>

<p><a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
</p>
<img src="images/cards.jpg" width="1131" height="707" alt="cards">
<br>

<h2 id="ex-cards">Ex Cards</h2>

<p></p>
<img src="images/excards.jpg" width="1000" height="653" alt="ex cards">
<br>
```

This way, you don't even need to reference an array. For every section you add, just ensure it has a consistent ID `'[name]-cards'` and it will automatically find it. You can also change the scroll speed if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling to an element with an id. You can simply just change the hash of the url and that's it.